# If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and its Fourier transform has compact support, then $f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n)\operatorname{sinc}(x-n)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

An old exam question I'm practicing with:

Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and assume that $\hat{f}$ (the Fourier transform of $f$) is supported on the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Let $\operatorname{sinc} (x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Prove that $$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n) \operatorname{sinc}(x-n).$$

The Fourier transform of a function $g$ is given by $\hat{g}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) e^{-2 \pi i x \omega} dx.$

It's not clear to me why the fact that $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported is important.

Comment: @Semiclassical thank you for the suggestion. I've added it to the problem statement

Comment: I'm not seeing how to make progress, but an obvious starting point is to compute the Fourier transform of the desired sum. When I do that, I get $$\mathcal{F}\left[ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n) \operatorname{sinc}(x-n)\right](\omega)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f(n) e^{-2\pi  n i} 1_{[-1/2\pi,1/2\pi]}.$$ This expression is dubious, if only because it's supported on $[-1/2\pi,1/2\pi]$ rather than $[-1/2,1/2]$. But if corrected it may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: One resolution to the prior issue would be if they used the _normalized_ sinc function, i.e., $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$. Absent that, I'm not sure what's going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the Fourier series $$\sum_k\hat{f}(y+k)= \sum_n \widehat{\hat{f}}(n)e^{2i \pi ny} = \sum_n f(n)e^{-2i \pi ny}$$
where $\widehat{\hat{f}}(n) = f(-n)$ is the Fourier inversion theorem.

That$f$ is $L^1$ means $\hat{f}$ is continuous and that it is supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$ means the LHS is well-defined, that the Fourier series converges in $L^2_{loc}$, that $f$ is continuous, and that  in $L^2$
$$\hat{f}(y) =1_{y \in [-1/2,1/2]} \sum_k\hat{f}(y+k)=1_{y \in [-1/2,1/2]}  \sum_n f(n)e^{-2i \pi ny}= \sum_n f(n)1_{y \in [-1/2,1/2]}  e^{-2i \pi ny}$$
The obtained equality thus holds in $L^1$ and inverse Fourier transform of both side gives
$$f(x) = \sum_n f(n)\frac{\sin(\pi (x-n))}{\pi (x-n)}$$

> The whole thing is called Shannon sampling theorem.

Comment: Why is the first equation true? To be more precise in my question, why can you express the sum of Fourier coefficients in this manner for an $L1$ function?

Comment: what is unclear to you. I define a periodic function and I start with its Fourier series

Comment: Why do you take $\hat{f}(y + k)$? I don't really get why the $k$ is there. Maybe I'm being dense, but if you could explain it, that'd be great!

Comment: The Fourier series is for periodic functions. When we say "the Fourier series of $|x|$" we mean the Fourier series of $\sum_k |x+k| 1_{x+k \in [0,1)}$. It is what you need to understand what happens when $\hat{f}$ isn't supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$.